# C++ inheritance of operator =

Tags: c++, inheritance

Please see this code fragment:

```
class Base {
public:
    const Base& foo      (const int&);
    const Base& operator=(const int&);
};

class Derived : public Base {};

void fn() {
    Derived   c;

    c.foo(3);  // compiles fine (as expected)
    c = 3;     // error: no match for ‘operator=’
}
```

The question is why is `operator=` not inherited from `Base` to `Derived` just like `foo()` is?

Is there something in the standard that makes `operator=` special with respect to inheritance?

Thanks

Comment: So, the standard link; http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ass#1; and to fix it (if not known); add a using to bring the operator into scope, `class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::operator=;
};`

Comment: Umm doesn't the linked question treat about copy assignment operator? I.e. in a form of `T& operator=(const T&)`, here we have and `int` as an argument. No one explains that every possible assingment operator is created implicitly. It that true?